# What's the additional benefit of Event Aggregator in Backbone Marionette compared to the built in Backbone Events?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, eventaggregator

I have recently looked at Backbone.Marionette.
It mentions the Event Aggregator in a way that seems to be something new.

https://github.com/toekneestuck/edgefonts-preview/blob/master/components/backbone.marionette/docs/marionette.eventaggregator.md

However I don't really see the added benefit to normal events. Doesn't following Code provide you the same?

```
var dispatcher = _.clone(Backbone.Events)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are almost exactly the same things. ([check the code](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr/blob/master/lib/backbone.wreqr.js#L246-L262))

The difference is that `EventAggregators` is a "class" which can be instantiated (wherea Backbone.Events act more as a mixin).

Being a "class", `EventAggregators` can be extended.

```
EventAggregators.extend({ /* your new methods */ });
```

The difference is really small, but goes a long way in reducing boilerplate necessary to create a event hub with custom prototype methods - and extending them in sub-eventAggregator.